# 301 URL encoding on IIS

Tags: jquery, .htaccess, redirect, iis, url-encoding

So I'm trying to set up 301 redirects on my site and all of new pages use JQUERY tabs, since **JQUERY tabs** use specific ids to open a new tab I tried setting up my 301's like /folder/file.html#tabId. So my 301's will actually look something like this:

- products/productname-overview.html -> /product/productname.html#overview
- products/productname-features.html -> /product/productname.html#features
- products/productname-specs.html -> /product/productname.html#specs

(So all my content will be in a single page now)

I'm currently working on **IIS 8** and I understand there are some rules that encode several characters on my 301's, so I also tried encoding my new urls but it seems that when it detects the %, ISS tells me is invalid.

- products/productname-overview.html -> /product/productname.html%23overview

Error log:
*A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (%).*

**Description:** An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

**Exception Details:** System.Web.HttpException: A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (%).

**Source Error:** An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

**StackTrace:** [HttpException (0x80004005): A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (%).]
   System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateInputIfRequiredByConfig() +12353279
   System.Web.PipelineStepManager.ValidateHelper(HttpContext context) +166

Is there a way to make a rule for only the "#" character? Any suggestions on how to fix this issue? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of redirecting to a fragment, you could pass the value of the fragment in a query string and retrieve it with js. Your redirect entry would look like:

```
products/productname-overview.html -> /product/productname.html?fragment=overview
```